# How do I mix jquery form validation (http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) and my own?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a need to use custom validation on my web form.

I have 2 or 3 select tags that display tour dates. They all defaults to an "empty" option (i.e. value parameter return ""). The user can select one or more dates.

**e.g.**

```
name: required field and uses the validation plugin

1st tour: user selected April 1 tour date

2nd tour user selected April 14 tour date

3rd tour: user opted not to join
```

If I use the validation plugin from the link above, my custom validation is never run when the submit button is pressed. (button tag is type submit. if I change button type to button, my custom javascript validation works but the name field is never checked.)

Another complexity is that the number of tours (thus the number of select tags) appearing on the page varies. it might be 2 this week and by next week, it'll be 4 (new ones were created since then).

I've looked at the api for the validation plugin but I don't think it would work. And I'm hoping to use it for fields that can make use it and only rely on custom validation for the "tricky" situation I described above.

Thanks

Comment: `jquery.Validation` allow custom rules to be run on form submission. You probably made an error in your code; can you add it?

Comment: It's best if you could show a coding attempt at this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Quote Title:**

> "How do I mix jquery form validation
>   (http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) and my own?"

Using the plugin's `addMethod()` method, there is no limit to what you can accomplish with this plugin.

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addMethod#namemethodmessage

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("myRule", function(value, element, params) { 
    // your custom validation function
    // return false; // represents failed validation
    // return true; // represents passed validation
}, jQuery.format("failed - your custom message"));
```

The arguments to the callback are:

- the current **value** of the validated element
- the **element** to be validated
- **parameters** specified for the method, e.g. for `min: 5` the parameter is `5`, for `range: [1, 5]` its `[1, 5]`